# Householder - Eliminating specific element of a vector

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

Given a column vector $$ a = \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} $$

specify a Householder transformation to annihilate the third component, $a_{3}$, *only*.

I have been reading this description of performing this and have been coming up short over and over.

[image]

How may I complete this problem? I am choosing ${a_{2}} = [4]$ here and I end up with $$ v = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\8\end{bmatrix} $$ but this is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you see the note on the bottom of the page/ http://homepages.rpi.edu/~lvovy/NC/node43.html ? Also, slide 22: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT4350/h08/undervisningsmateriale/chap17slides.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is $H=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0.6&0.8\\0&0.8&-0.6\end{bmatrix}$ sending vector
$a=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$ onto vector $b=\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Explanations: (The way I have proceeded is different from the way indicated by your book.)

1) The crucial step is to take an image vector $b$ that has the same norm as $a$ (because an Householder transformation is an isometry).

2) I define the difference $c=\dfrac{a-b}{\|a-b\|}$: this is clearly a direction of the symmetry which sends $a$ onto $b$. One obtains $c=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\begin{bmatrix}0\\-2\\4\end{bmatrix}$.

3) The matrix is given by the classical formula $H=I_3-2cc^T$.

Remark: the block structure of this matrix $H$ displays a symmetry in the $xOy$ plane, with its classical structure $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a \end{bmatrix}$ with $a^2+b^2=1$.