# Householder matrix to annihilate components

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a tutorial problem to start with vector $$\begin{bmatrix}12\\5\\12\end{bmatrix}$$ and design a Householder transformation which annihilates the third component but leaves the first unchanged $$\begin{bmatrix}12\\?\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

I have looked at a few other answers but none quite seem to help me.

[Householder - Eliminating specific element of a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668169/householder-eliminating-specific-element-of-a-vector): This is pretty much the same question just different numbers. I get lost with the jargon in the accepted answer.

[Householder reflections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284532/householder-reflections): This answer is on the same theme of what I am asking but the accepted answer is too vague for me.

I have these formulae: $\bf{v}=\bf{x} + sign(x_k)\lVert x\rVert \bf{e}_k$; $H=I-\frac{\bf{vv^T}}{\bf{v^Tv}}$

I have had many false starts on this that have led nowhere. Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Your formula for $H$ is missing a factor of $2$. What you have here computes the projection onto the reflecting plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you transfor only a vector (and not a matrix), keep in mind that the housholder-matrix is orthogonal. This means:

$$||Hx||_2=||x||_2$$

In your case, this would mean that $$||H\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 12\end{bmatrix} ||_2 = ||\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 12\end{bmatrix} ||_2 = 13$$

therefor, the value you are looking for is either $+13$ or$-13$.

For 2d cases, you could create a drawing (assuming that you know how householder works):

[image]

Because your first component (5) is positive, you mirror-axis would be the the line without an arrow. Now, mirroring your vector ends up with a vector with positive x-value ($+13$)$.

If you have more dimensions, you should just calculate the housholder matrix.

Comment: Note that the non-arrow line is equal to x + sign(x_2) ||x|| e_k

Comment: The required Householder vector is just the difference between $x$ and its image, regardless of the dimensionality of the ambient space.

Answer (score 0):

First, let’s fix your formula for $H$, which is missing a factor of $2$. The correct formula is $H=I-2{\mathbf v\mathbf v^T\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}$. What you have is a projection onto the reflecting hyperplane.

Reflections preserve lengths, so the first order of business is to choose a value for the $?$ such that the vector and its image have the same norm. The numbers in this exercise were chose to make this calculation easy. Equating the norms and solving for the missing component produces $\pm13$.

Moving on, “Householder reflection” is just a fancy name for reflection in a hyperplane. This hyperplane is the angle bisector of a vector and its reflection, so a normal to it is simply the difference between a known vector and its image. In this case, then, you can take either $\mathbf v=(12,5,12)-(12,13,0)=(0,-8,12)$ or $\mathbf v=(12,5,12)-(12,-13,0)=(0,18,12)$.

If you prefer, we can derive this algebraically instead. If $\mathbf x'=(I-{\mathbf v\mathbf v^T\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf x$, then $$\mathbf x-\mathbf x' =\mathbf x -\left( \mathbf x - {\mathbf v^T\mathbf x\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf v \right) =  {\mathbf v^T\mathbf x\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf v.$$ In other words, $\mathbf v$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf x-\mathbf x'$, but since the denominator in the reflection formula normalizes $\mathbf v$, its (nonzero) length is irrelevant so we can simply take $\mathbf v=\mathbf x-\mathbf x'$.